# Facet Api and acive filters

Tags: blocks, search

In my website, I'm using [ApcheSolr](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) with [facet api](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi) and with some configuration I listed facets blocks and it works fine!

But now I want to create a block that list to me the active filter chosen by user

I read some facet api documentation but I'm lost !!

Can anyone help me!

Tanks in advance.

Comment: Facet API module has this submodule.

Answer (score 1):

Enable Current Search submodule, you can also install [Current Search Links](https://drupal.org/project/current_search_links)

> Extension to the Facet API current search blocks module. Instead of just showing the current search it turns the current search keywords into links that you can drop from the search.

Comment: this module is enabled in my website, and the block is added to sidebar named (Current search: Standard) but nothing appear!!

Comment: @Boussettamoez May be you installed it incorrectly or your configurations are not correct.. https://drupal.org/node/1375674

Comment: This module definitely works, I use it in a bunch of different sites to good effect

Comment: may be I have something wrong in my site configuration!! it sill not working!!

Comment: I'll check and return here if I found something wrong!